# printing sum of same values from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using for loop to go through the list like:

```
for c in classes:
    print(c.get(‘class’), c.get(‘money’,{})[0].get(‘totalspent’))
```

I get results:

```
classs1  10
class2   20
class3   10
class2   30
class3   20
```

I am trying to figure out a way to get something like:

```
class1  10
class2  50
class3  30
```

how can I do this? I tried making a dictionary and putting everything in that under for loop but keep getting errors.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide an example of your "classes" object -- presumably a list of dictionaries or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

output = defaultdict(int)

for c in classes:
    output[c.get('class')] += c.get('money', {})[0].get('totalspent', 0)
#                                                                    ^ Note the 0 as default

print(output)
```

`output` will be a dictionary where the key is the name of the class the value is the total.

Comment: Thank you so much!!